# Crashlytics And Android 6.0.1

Tags: android, crashlytics, twitter-fabric

I have started facing this weird situation in where now my crash dumps are not getting uploaded to Crashlytics. See the following text on crash.

`8-14 01:09:59.818 783-1201/? W/ActivityManager: Force finishing activity com.abc/.main.LandingScreen 
08-14 01:09:59.891 783-879/? I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4 
08-14 01:10:00.027 27364-27404/? I/CrashlyticsCore: Crashlytics report upload complete: 57AFFD26006F-0001-6AE4-AB5986A80D97.cls 
08-14 01:10:00.347 783-796/? W/ActivityManager: Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{64bbc2d u0 com.abc/.main.LandingScreen t39 f} 
08-14 01:10:00.439 5266-27204/? W/LocationOracle: No location history returned by ContextManager 
08-14 01:10:00.491 1575-1694/? D/GCoreFlp: FLP HAL exists but batch size is <= 0. Disabling FLP HAL.`

It says the dump is uploaded but I never get any emails regarding this crash and other crashes also I don't see anything related to crashes on my Fabric dashboard. Interestingly enough I have another Android Device using the same OS but different provider and I get dumps and emails. Is there anything specific to my phone I need to switch ON for this to work?

Can you please tell me why?

> Phone not giving dumps : LG Nexus 5 Android 6.0.1, API 23 and Crashlytics Version 2.6.1.
>
> Phone giving dumps : Moto G4 Android 6.0.1, API 23 and Crashlytics Version 2.6.1.